# Get number of formal parameters in PHP

Tags: php, optional-parameters

I know you can use `func_num_args` to get the number of actual arguments passed in. Is there any way to get the number of formal parameters?

Example:

```php
<?php

function optional($a, $b = null) {
    echo func_num_args();
}

optional(1); // 1
optional(1, 1); // 2
optional(1, 1, 1); // 3
```

I want a way to get `2` in each of those calls to `optional`, without hard-coding it.

Comment: You can probably do something like that using PHP reflection, but I have no experience w/ it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is with [`ReflectionFunction`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php), e.g.:

```
function optional($a, $b = null) {
    return (new ReflectionFunction(__FUNCTION__))->getNumberOfParameters();
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I didn't realize these functions were part of the core in PHP 5.